# operator Overloading in C#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

```
class Point
{
    private int m_PointX;
    private int m_PointY;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        m_PointX = x;
        m_PointY = y;
    }

    public static Point operator+(Point point1, Point point2)
    {
        Point P = new Point();
        P.X = point1.X + point2.X;
        P.Y = point1.Y + point2.Y;

        return P;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Point P1 = new Point(10,20);
Point P2 = new Point(30,40)
P1+P2; // operator overloading
```

1. Is it necessary to always declare the operator overloading function as static? What is the reason behind this?
2. If I want to overload + to accept the expression like 2+P2, how to do this?

Comment: The reason #1 is the way it is is so you can easily accomplish #2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes. Because you aren't dealing with instances always with the operators.
2. Just change the types to what you want.

Here is an example for #2

```
public static Point operator+(int value, Point point2)
{
 // logic here.
}
```

You will have to do the other way with the parameters if you want `P2 + 2` to work.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, you need to define them as static. They're not instance methods, they can operate on `null`s as well.
2. You'll have to define an operator overload where one of the parameters are of type `int`

Comment: If you are adding int + point instead of point + int, will it still do the operation correctly?

Comment: in C++ , if the operator overloading is defined by member function then we need to pass one parameters or if defined by friend function we need to defined two parameters. Is it possible to declare the operator overloading method as memeber function?

Comment: No, it is not possible to declare it as an instance member, you need to declare it as static. Also, to handle `int + point` as well as `point + int` you need to declare two operator overloads. The reason is that `int + point` could produce a different result than `point + int`. For instance, the first might add the distance from origin to the int, as a number, whereas the second might offset the point by a given value. (ie. one produces a new int, the other a new point.)

Comment: what is the reason that made to make the operators overloading as static?

Comment: I don't know, you would have to ping Eric Lippert or one of the compiler guys. In any case, they *are* static, and there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the previous answers talk about your questions, so I'm not going to intrude on those, but here is an example of using 2+P:

```
   public static Point operator+(int yourInt, Point point)
    {
        Point P = new Point();
        P.X = point.X + yourInt;
        P.Y = point.Y + yourInt;

        return P;
    }
```